# Why can't my chrome extension use HTML5 postMessage to communicate with a frame I inject?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

So, I have a page on DomainA, and, using a Chrome extension, I'm injecting some javascript that inserts iframe that points to DomainB.

```
$("body").append("<iframe id='someFrame' src='http://www.domainB.com' width='300' height='800'></iframe>");
```

I also inject a  some javascript into DomainA that attempts to get the iframe's contentWindow.  I want to use the HTML5 postMessage api on it.

```
$("body").append("<a class='myLink'>Post Message</a>");
$(".myLink").click(function(){
    var frameElem = document.getElementById("someFrame"); 
    console.log("frameElem: " + frameElem); //succeeds

var contentWin = frameElem.contentWindow;
console.log("contentWin : " + contentWin); //undefined

//can't do this since contentWin is undefined: 
//contentWin.postMessage("data", "*");
});
```

However, the contentWindow property is undefined.  Why is that, and how can I get around it?  If I put this extension code in a webpage it'll work fine by itself.

Thanks!

(pardon the crappy jquery/javascript)

Comment: Are you just trying to make a cross domain request? Or you need those iframes?

Comment: I need the iframe to show content on another server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know it's kind of lame to answer my own question, but I did some more digging, and found a bug filed on Chromium for the issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20773

I found this link in the chromium extensions group: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/1d4b68f0971ef190/3446a7e82848351c?lnk=gst&q=contentWindow#3446a7e82848351c

Comment: It's not lame. What's lame is *not* posting the answer if you find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's for the same reasons why content scripts cannot access window object of their parent page. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955803/page-variables-in-content-script), and it has a link to a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

You need to embed an iframe in your root frame which sends requests to a client frame, which then sends commands back to the root website as shown in the following example. This is known as the 'one-way pipe' hack.:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735305.aspx

[image]

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.  I don't need to utilize a hack for a chrome extension.  I'm trying to figure out why the contentWindow property is undefined so I can use postMessage.