# chrome extension throws "not defined" on defined variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access a local var using a chrome extension. 
When trying `console.info(myVar)` inside a page script, I am getting `myVar is not defined`

However, when using the chrome developer tools and executing the same snippet in the debugging console, I am getting the full content of myVar.

Same behaviour when trying to access `window.myVar`, which is simply `undefined` when printing through a chrome extension.

Injecting a script tag into the body, using the following snippet through dev tools and page script, results in the exact same behaviour.

```
   $("body").append($("<script />", {
      html: "console.info(myVar);"
   }));
```

Variable gets printed when executing in dev tools but javascript error in pagescripts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page variables in content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955803/page-variables-in-content-script)

Comment: injecting a script tag into the pages body (executing `console.info(myVar)` has exactly the same result as stated above. This must be something else

Comment: However, injecting through chrome dev tools prints the variable without any problems.

Comment: "content scripts have some limitations. They cannot: [...] Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts" http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: By directly accessing, yes. Injecting a script right into the pages body SHOULD work fine though

Comment: Indeed, a `script` element injected into the page can access the page's variables. But it will run in the context of the page and not your extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632133/oleg) and me found the source of the problem in a [chat session.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30732/discussion-between-dabido-and-oleg)

I tried injecting the script using the following snippet:

```
   $("body").append($("<script />", {
      html: "console.info(myVar);"
   }));
```

As [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632133/oleg) wrote in his answer, it looks like the `console.info` part gets executed before arriving in the pages body, resulting in having the extension context here. The non jQuery version works fine though:

```
var g = document.createElement('script'); 
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
g.text = "console.info(myVar);" 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
```

Answer (score 5):

What you see is expected behavior.

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They **have access to the DOM of the page** they are injected into,
>   but **not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page**.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse:
>   JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
>   variables defined by content scripts.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment

When you run `console.info(myVar);` from the page, the console of Chrome dev tools or from the injected script, it runs in the context of the page and thus sees the variable as defined.

However, when running the same code from inside of your extension code, you're operating in a completely different environment, so `myVar` is undefined.

You can work around this using shared DOM perhaps.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication

### EDIT

Unless someone corrects me, the `console.info(myVar);` code below is injected into `script` element while still being executed in the context of the extension:

```
$("<script />", {
    html: "console.info(myVar);" // myVar points to extension's myVar, not page's
});
```

A simple test can be run by logging `chrome.extension` object or declaring `myVar` inside of the contentscript – the `chrome.extension` will be available and `myVar` will be logged exactly as defined in the contentscript.

The suggestion is to use an external script (which is also better for modularity), add it to `web_accessible_resources` and create a `script` element with a `src` property pointing to that external script.

The example extension code below alerts "test" when loading the test.html page with extension enabled.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Just a test.",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "myscript.js"
    ]
}
```

**test.html** (the visited page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.test = 'test';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**contentscript.js**

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('myscript.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

**myscript.js** (this is the external script that will run in the context of the page)

```
alert(window.test);
```

Comment: Doesn't explain why the injected script tag can't see the pages variable, even though it is executed in the pages context - injecting it through the dev tools works fine though. See my edit above

Comment: Yes. Plus the page itself ships jQuery too

Comment: And you're sure it's the same error? Not something like "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"?

Comment: 100% sure. Plus, found out that the even the window object differs with some attributes when printing through injected script tag by pagescript and dev tools.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: On my side, I have absolutely no problems injecting a script and logging the dummy `myVar` variable (I'm not using jQuery though). Perhaps you're running your extension code before `myVar` is created?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30732/discussion-between-dabido-and-oleg)