# How to execute a callback on the devtools page from page's JS?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to write a Chrome devtools extension for a JS SDK we have developed. This SDK has an API `addEventListener` (the events are not DOM events) that I would like to use to be able to display all the events that are being published in the devtools panel I made.

Basically I would like to be able to have the following code in my devtools page script :

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
            "mySDKonTheContentPage", function(result, isException){
                mySDK =result;
                mySDK.addEventListener("myEvent", function(){
                   doSomethingInDevtoolsUI();
               });
            });
```

Since content scripts don't have access (do they?) to the page's JS objects, I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Not much clear about your question. However according to the last line, if you want to access page javascript variables through content scripts, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955803/page-variables-in-content-script

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if the question is unclear. I thought that writing a devtools extension would give the extension all access to what's going on the page, but apparently not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the script on your page, you can use `window.postMessage` to send your data to the content script. From there you can set up communication between the content script and the DevTools panel via a background page.

**See:** [Messaging from Injected Scripts to the DevTools Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#evaluated-scripts-to-devtools) and [Messaging from Content Scripts to the DevTools Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#content-script-to-devtools) for examples of this in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid there was no direct way of doing this. I'll try with the injected-script => content-script => background => devtool panel way then :p

Comment: If it helps anyone, I made a simple github repo implementing this: https://github.com/psykhi/chrome-devtools-extension

Comment: @psykhi That's really useful. Thanks for posting this.