# Chrome Extension: Iinitialize Selectize.js from HTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, selectize.js

I am developing a Chrome Extension this means that my script is running in an "Isolated world" ,however,  I need to change the value of  that is using **selectize**.

Since I only have access to the DOM HTML.

Does anyone know how I can re-intialize and or access to the instance of selectize to change the value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension: Get Page Variables in Content Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955803/chrome-extension-get-page-variables-in-content-script)

Comment: @GergelySzabo you were correct that fixed it. Thank you, you saved my day and part of the night... The other option involved a lot of coding