# Reading WEB Page Variables With Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**I am Working to Create a Youtube Video Downloading Extension Based on JS**

I have extracted the link of youtube videos. But the problem comes when I want to access the variables on youtube page with the extension but I cannot read the variables. 
The Js variables being used by the WEB page in Script elements .

I am totally new in Chrome Extension developing.
If you can help me in this it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What variables are you talking about?

Comment: The Js variables being used by the WEB page in Script elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension: Get Page Variables in Content Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955803/chrome-extension-get-page-variables-in-content-script)

Comment: thanks everyone but i solved it using eval method.

Comment: I used another method to get the variables from that specific script tag...

    var y = document.getElementsByName('body') ;
    var a = document.getElementById("player") ;
    var b =  a.getElementsByTagName("script") ;
    var c = b[1].innerText ;
    var link = " " ;
    eval(c) ;

i used this method to use the variables of script tag in content script