# How to get the variable defined inside a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Note: This question is for chrome extension that I'm building and I only have access to HTML source through console.

I'm trying to get a Javascript object that is inside a script tag.
I have the script tag inside the HTML source file:

```
<script id="myscript">
const data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
</script>
```

I can access it in the Chrome console using:

```
document.getElementById('myscript');
```

This returns the script tag as a HTML tag.

How can I access the data variable that is defined inside it?

Comment: No. You could use globals or modules (I recommend the latter) to solve this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @FZs The HTML is not my source.

Comment: @Emmanuel That is not possible. console.log(data) is not defined. All I have is a <script> HTML tag.

Comment: @costaparas I'm building a chrome extension. The website has some data defined inside a script tag that I want access to.

Comment: @abdullahDev If they made it global (as in your posted code) then you can access it globally. If they did not, you can't do anything else about it.

Comment: @abdullahDev In that case, you will want to take a look at [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955803/chrome-extension-get-page-variables-in-content-script).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the object stored in the variable by using the variable name.

```
const data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
console.log(data); //logs the object
```

You can access the properties of the object using dot or square bracket notation

```
//dot notation
console.log(data.a); // 1

//square bracket notation
console.log(data["b"]);// 2
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't clarify I can't do that. I'm building a chrome extension and I only have page source.

Comment: @abdullahDev What are you trying to do with the object ?

Comment: I'm building a chrome extension, that runs a content script when I visit website X. Inside the source of the website, there is a script tag, that has an ID and an object variable. I want to get that variable.

Comment: @Stephenio OP wants to read the values in a script on the page, but due to the fact that Chrome extensions exist in a separate context, it's impossible to simply read the variables in like you're doing in your answer - they're like two different webpages.

Answer (score 0):

Many good methods can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3955803/10221765). But if you don't want to mess around with inserting scripts and reading values back via less intended methods (and potentially if you're slightly mad) you could use `eval`:

```
eval(document.getElementById("myscript").innerHTML);
console.log(data["a"]); // 1
```

I *do not* recommend doing this, it's only used as a simple method that works in the case you've described. I would highly recommend using methods found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3955803/10221765) instead.