# Insert a button to current page by chrome extension, but some methods are not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a very simple chrome extension which adds a button to current page.

#### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "chrome-extension-tabs-executescript-add-button-demo",
  "description": "Chrome Extension Add Button Demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

#### popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chrome Extension Add Button Demo</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

#### popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "add-button.js"
}, function() {
    console.log("add-button.js injected")
})
```

#### add-button.js

```
var button = document.createElement("button")

button.innerText = "This is the inserted button, click on me!"
button['id'] = 'inserted'
button['data-name'] = 'name1'
button.onclick = function() {
    alert('clicked!')
}
button.fun = function() {
    alert('fun!')
}

document.body.appendChild(button)
```

#### Problems

It's almost working well, that if we clicked the extension icon for current page, and type following code in browser's console:

```
let button = document.getElementById('inserted');
button.click();
```

there is an alert means it's working.

But when calling `fun()` on it:

```
button.fun();
```

it reports such error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: button.fun is not a function
```

Can't understand why `fun` is missing.

Also provide a simple but complete demo if you need it: https://github.com/chrome-demos/chrome-extension-tabs-executescript-add-button-demo

---

I see in other answers it says content scripts [run in a "isolated world"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162742/342235), that the page and the content script and only see the same DOM, but not the variables defined in each other. My question puzzled me is, both `onclick` and `fun` are all functions defined on the DOM, why only one of them can work well.

I guess, the code run in content script

```
button.onclick = function() {
    alert('clicked!')
}
button.fun = function() {
    alert('fun!')
}
```

defines two functions, but they are not considered the same.

The `onclick` is a standard attribute of the shared DOM, so it adds to the DOM directly, which can be seen in page context.

But the `fun` method is not, so won't be added to the shared DOM, instead, it adds to somewhere else (maybe a child instance of the shared DOM), just stay in the scope of chrome content script.

Is my guess correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right. 
Web pages and content-scripts share the same event model but have isolated variables and properties.

When you assign the function to the `button.onclick` you actually set a handler for the existed event model. *(btw, using `onlick=` is not good practice)*. 
But by assigning a function to the `.fun` - you are creating a new property, which will be isolated from the web page.