# firefox extension cannot register onClick handler

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

My minimal failing example of JavaScript for a Mozilla/Firefox extension using a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) adds a paragraph to web pages and tries to register a function `i_clicked()` to be called when the user clicks there.

```
console.log("step 0");

function i_clicked() {
    console.log("step 2");
}

console.log("step 1");

let p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = "Click here";
p.setAttribute("onClick", "i_clicked()");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

The log shows "step 0" and "step 1", but when I click on the paragraph, the console says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: i_clicked is not defined`. I conclude that the page cannot access the function I defined in the content script. How should this be done instead?

Comment: Have you tried using standard APIs instead? [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yes, `p.addEventListener("onclick", i_clicked);` instead of setting the `onClick`. Then just nothing happens when I click, not even an error. Also with `"onClick"`.
´

Comment: The event name is `click`, not `onclick`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, thanks, this gets me one step furter, `p.addEventListener("click", i_clicked, true);` registers the function and clicking fires `"step 2"` once. However, the second click does not do anything again.

Comment: Although it is about Chome extensions, the problem is so similar that I add here a reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162520/function-not-defined-creating-a-chrome-extension-content-script

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions by Sebastian Simon in the original comments seem to do the trick.

Here's an example manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "OnClick demo",
    "description": "From Stack Overflow question",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and `content.js`

```js
console.log("step 0");

function i_clicked() {
    console.log("step 2");
}

console.log("step 1");

let p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = "Click here";
p.addEventListener('click', i_clicked);
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Here, I changed your original `p.setAttribute("onClick", "i_clicked()");` into `p.addEventListener('click', i_clicked);`

When loaded as a temporary add-on on Firefox, I can see the click being activated each time.

[image: console output saying "step 2" and having been run 8 times]