# Add GLOBAL JavaScript function in browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there any way, to create a global function (i.e. `MyFunction`) in a browser, so, I can execute it on any site, on any page (because browser will know it).

Comment: Of course. Create an extension. For example in this answer new function is added to `window`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051205/adding-custom-functionality-into-chromes-console/9051533#9051533