# Why can I change HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play from console, but not via user script?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, google-chrome-devtools, userscripts

If I open the Chrome developer tools console and change `HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play`, it works just fine.

```
> HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play = function(){debugger;}
function (){debugger;}
> HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play
function (){debugger;}
```

However, if I change it from a user script, the function always seems to revert to the native implementation.

```
> HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play
function play() { [native code] }
```

I have verified that the user script loads correctly, and I even tried an ugly setInterval approach, to see if at least that works:

```
var myFunction = function(){debugger;};
window.setInterval(function(){
  if (window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play != myFunction)
    window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play = myFunction;
}, 900);
```

But even with this I always end back up with the native implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Injecting JS functions into the page from a Greasemonkey script on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303147/injecting-js-functions-into-the-page-from-a-greasemonkey-script-on-chrome/2303228#2303228):

> The only way to communicate with the code running on the page in
>   Chrome is through the DOM, so you'll have to use a hack like inserting
>   a  tag with your code. Note that this may prove buggy if your
>   script needs to run before everything else on the page.
>
> EDIT: Here's how the Nice Alert extension does this:
>
> ```
> function main () {
>   // ...
>   window.alert = function() {/* ... */};
>   // ...
> }
>
> var script = document.createElement('script');
> script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+ main +')();'));
> (document.body || document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
> ```