# Inject JS function with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a pretty simple HTML code that displays browsers current working area:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
wwidth  = document.body.clientWidth;
wheight = document.body.clientHeight;
alert("Working area is: " + wwidth + "x" + wheight);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to tamper these values with my own ones using the following Greasemonkey script (I have used the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303147/injecting-js-functions-into-the-page-from-a-greasemonkey-script-on-chrome) as a reference) which does not seem to work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Resolution
// @namespace   One
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function main () {
Object.defineProperty(body, "clientWidth", {value: '1000'});
Object.defineProperty(body, "clientHeight", {value: '1000'});
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+ main +')();'));
(document.body || document.head ||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```

This is my first work with javascript and some may find this to be a pretty simple issue but I simply can not find a solution to it so any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If what you're trying to do is reset the height and width of the browser, well I don't think you can do that using JavaScript.

Comment: I think those values are read-only; they're updated by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic javascript for this, see example https://jsfiddle.net/5os5r8e2/1/

```
<body>
  <input type="button" value="change height" onclick="cHeight()">
  <input type="button" value="change width" onclick="cWidth()">
</body>
<script>
  wwidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  wheight = document.body.clientHeight;
  alert("Working area is: " + wwidth + "x" + wheight);

  function cHeight() {
    document.body.style.height = "1000px";
  }

  function cWidth() {
    document.body.style.width = "50%";
  }

</script>
```